# Twitter Bootstrap: Getting Form Inputs and Buttons to be same the height in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, twitter-bootstrap

Using [Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) I have a `input-append` form:

```
<form class="bs-docs-example">
  <div class="input-append">
    <input type="text" id="form-input" class="span2">
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="form-btn">Go!</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I customized the form input and button to have this styling:

```
#form-input {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0px 6px;
}

#form-btn {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

The input field and button in Firefox is exactly aligned but the button in Chrome is off my 2px in height so I have to put it to `52px`. This cannot be done since it messes up the Firefox form. How can I get them to have the same alignment in both browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found the problem. It was a Firefox issue. Firefox has a property called `moz-box-sizing` that makes this small error. You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

What I did was simply turn this:

```
// Form Inputs //

input[type="text"], 
input[type="password"], 
input[type="date"], 
input[type="datetime"], 
input[type="datetime-local"], 
input[type="month"], 
input[type="week"], 
input[type="email"], 
input[type="number"], 
input[type="search"], 
input[type="tel"], 
input[type="time"], 
input[type="url"], 
textarea {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Into this: `-moz-box-sizing: inherit;`

This is my new code with the added box-sizing change above and with the help of [kmiyashiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146612/kmiyashiro) specifying button use of `line-height` instead:

```
#form-input {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#form-btn {
 line-height: 50px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you inspect the bootstrap styles, you will see that they do not explicitly define the `height` of the button, but the `line-height`.

- Make sure they have the same vertical `padding`, `font-size`, and `border-size`.
- Set the `height` and `line-height` of the **input** to `x`
- Set the `line-height` of the **button** to `x`

sample code:

```
#form-input,
#form-button {
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#form-input {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same results just now it's the other way around with the Firefox `form-input` being a little off. I set both of the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to `0` and still no good. Putting the line height of the `input-form` to `50px` makes the Chrome input have a line for the input that fills up the whole input. I want it to stay the size of `16px` font though. Also, my border size is the same for both.

Comment: Try changing one thing at a time to until you figure out which property is causing the difference. Start out with default bootstrap styles, then add each of your rules one by one.